# Function that sorts words by punctuation in excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a task to create reversed alphabetized list in excel. I thought it was easy to do, created a function to write words from behind and sorted list by that. It would work... if my language was English. But my language is Slovak, which uses bunch of characters with punctuation like á, ä, ô, š etc. And syllables containing these letters should be grouped. For example words *strany, hrany, planý, plány, vraný, vrany* should be sorted in order *hrany, strany, vrany, plány, planý, vraný*. Instead of, these words are sorted in order *plány,
planý,
hrany,
strany,
vrany,
vraný*.

I thought that switching language is enough, but seems all collates sort this way. I have tried to switch from ISO 8859-2 to unicode and several other encodings, but it didn't make a change as well.

So my question is, is there any encoding+locale setting in windows 10 that will do it? And if not, is it possible to do it through VBA function?

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: You may need to write a routine that breaks words into syllables, in order to develop your custom sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by myself with pretty simple solution:

1, get hex codes of the characters

2, translate them into unique code containing only ascii chars (a = aa, á = ab...)

3, sort this translated row